# MYSQL Count and Sort Results

Tags: mysql

I have written a query to total and count results and perform some functions on those results (calculating percentages, etc).  My query works, but I am certain there is a probably ab better way to do this.  You will see it is a very long-winded query.  I created a Survey which saved results in a database.

This query sorts the results by course, and then it totals the amount of answers for each question, then it allots points to each question based on these results, then it creates a percentage based on points allotted for each question, then it gives a grand percentage.

As mentioned before, this query works, but let me know if you have a better way to do this.

```
select 
y.Course as Course,
y.ins as Instructor,
y.comp as Completed,
((y.q1_percent+y.q2_percent+y.q3_percent+y.q4_percent+y.q5_percent+y.q6_percent)/6) as 'Total Percent',
y.Q1_percent as Q1,
y.Q2_percent as Q2,
y.Q3_percent as Q3,
y.Q4_percent as Q4,
y.Q5_percent as Q5,
y.Q6_percent as Q6,
y.comp*5 as 'Avail Points',
y.Q1_pts as 'Q1 Points',
y.Q2_pts as 'Q2 Points',
y.Q3_pts as 'Q3 Points',
y.Q4_pts as 'Q4 Points',
y.Q5_pts as 'Q5 Points',
y.Q6_pts as 'Q6 Points'

from ( select

    z.course as Course,
z.ins as ins,
z.comp as comp,
    z.Avail_Points as Avail_Pts,
    z.Q1_rating as Q1_Pts,
    (z.Q1_rating / z.Avail_Points * 100) as Q1_Percent,
    z.Q2_rating as Q2_Pts,
    (z.Q2_rating / z.Avail_Points * 100) as Q2_Percent,
    z.Q3_rating as Q3_Pts,
    (z.Q3_rating / z.Avail_Points * 100) as Q3_Percent,
    z.Q4_rating as Q4_Pts,
    (z.Q4_rating / z.Avail_Points * 100) as Q4_Percent,
    z.Q5_rating as Q5_Pts,
    (z.Q5_rating / z.Avail_Points * 100) as Q5_Percent,
    z.Q6_rating as Q6_Pts,
    (z.Q6_rating / z.Avail_Points * 100) as Q6_Percent
from
    (select 
        x.course as course,
x.ins, x.comp,
            (x.comp * 5) as Avail_Points,
            ((x.q1_SD * 1) + (x.q1_D * 2) + (x.q1_NDA * 3) + (x.q1_A * 4) + (x.q1_SA * 5)) as q1_Rating,
            ((x.q2_SD * 1) + (x.q2_D * 2) + (x.q2_NDA * 3) + (x.q2_A * 4) + (x.q2_SA * 5)) as q2_Rating,
            ((x.q3_SD * 1) + (x.q3_D * 2) + (x.q3_NDA * 3) + (x.q3_A * 4) + (x.q3_SA * 5)) as q3_Rating,
            ((x.q4_SD * 1) + (x.q4_D * 2) + (x.q4_NDA * 3) + (x.q4_A * 4) + (x.q4_SA * 5)) as q4_Rating,
            ((x.q5_SD * 1) + (x.q5_D * 2) + (x.q5_NDA * 3) + (x.q5_A * 4) + (x.q5_SA * 5)) as q5_Rating,
            ((x.q6_SD * 1) + (x.q6_D * 2) + (x.q6_NDA * 3) + (x.q6_A * 4) + (x.q6_SA * 5)) as q6_Rating
    from
        (select 
        concat(c.course_num, ' - ', c.name) as Course,
            concat(i.fname, ' ', i.lname) as ins,
            count(a.pk_ansID) as 'comp',
            sum(a.q1 = 0) + sum(a.q2 = 0) + sum(a.q3 = 0) + sum(a.q4 = 0) + sum(a.q5 = 0) + sum(a.q6 = 0) as NR,
            sum(a.q1 = 1) + sum(a.q2 = 1) + sum(a.q3 = 1) + sum(a.q4 = 1) + sum(a.q5 = 1) + sum(a.q6 = 1) as SD,
            sum(a.q1 = 2) + sum(a.q2 = 2) + sum(a.q3 = 2) + sum(a.q4 = 2) + sum(a.q5 = 2) + sum(a.q6 = 2) as D,
            sum(a.q1 = 3) + sum(a.q2 = 3) + sum(a.q3 = 3) + sum(a.q4 = 3) + sum(a.q5 = 3) + sum(a.q6 = 3) as NDA,
            sum(a.q1 = 4) + sum(a.q2 = 4) + sum(a.q3 = 4) + sum(a.q4 = 4) + sum(a.q5 = 4) + sum(a.q6 = 4) as A,
            sum(a.q1 = 5) + sum(a.q2 = 5) + sum(a.q3 = 5) + sum(a.q4 = 5) + sum(a.q5 = 5) + sum(a.q6 = 5) as SA,
            sum(a.q1 = 0) as q1_NR,
            sum(a.q2 = 0) as q2_NR,
            sum(a.q3 = 0) as q3_NR,
            sum(a.q4 = 0) as q4_NR,
            sum(a.q5 = 0) as q5_NR,
            sum(a.q6 = 0) as q6_NR,
            sum(a.q1 = 1) as q1_SD,
            sum(a.q2 = 1) as q2_SD,
            sum(a.q3 = 1) as q3_SD,
            sum(a.q4 = 1) as q4_SD,
            sum(a.q5 = 1) as q5_SD,
            sum(a.q6 = 1) as q6_SD,
            sum(a.q1 = 2) as q1_D,
            sum(a.q2 = 2) as q2_D,
            sum(a.q3 = 2) as q3_D,
            sum(a.q4 = 2) as q4_D,
            sum(a.q5 = 2) as q5_D,
            sum(a.q6 = 2) as q6_D,
            sum(a.q1 = 3) as q1_NDA,
            sum(a.q2 = 3) as q2_NDA,
            sum(a.q3 = 3) as q3_NDA,
            sum(a.q4 = 3) as q4_NDA,
            sum(a.q5 = 3) as q5_NDA,
            sum(a.q6 = 3) as q6_NDA,
            sum(a.q1 = 4) as q1_A,
            sum(a.q2 = 4) as q2_A,
            sum(a.q3 = 4) as q3_A,
            sum(a.q4 = 4) as q4_A,
            sum(a.q5 = 4) as q5_A,
            sum(a.q6 = 4) as q6_A,
            sum(a.q1 = 5) as q1_SA,
            sum(a.q2 = 5) as q2_SA,
            sum(a.q3 = 5) as q3_SA,
            sum(a.q4 = 5) as q4_SA,
            sum(a.q5 = 5) as q5_SA,
            sum(a.q6 = 5) as q6_SA
    from
        survey_answers a
    left outer join course c ON c.pk_courseID = a.fk_courseID
    left outer join instructor i ON (i.pk_insID = c.fk_insID)
    group by a.fk_courseID) x) z) y
```

Comment: a better way to do that is to use a programming language to do the calculation instead of sql

Comment: can you post a schema? or build a sql fiddle?

Comment: Build a fiddle !! your query it to long to just take a look over it !

Comment: are you looking for performance advice or different way of writing the query ?